# iReport - How to move a Summary Pie Chart on the first page of the report and not at the end?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, pie-chart

Is it possible to have a Summary Pie chart as the first page of my multi-page report (right before the Detail band)? I need to display my Summary band as the first page when report is printed.

You advice is appreciated!

Siyan

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a dataset just for the Pie chart? I think if you do that you should be able to place the Pie chart in whatever band you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Rogiller said: You can use a fake group (group on true) with only one group header band (print when $V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1). Then use a dataset to fill the chart and use Report as the ExecutionTime, however this can be costly if you have a database query because it will execute twice.

You could also use a subreport.

Alternatively vote for this feature request:

[0005115: Option to render summary band before report details](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=5115)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by setting Evaluation Time at "Report":

```xml
<pie3DChart>
     <chart isShowLegend="true" evaluationTime="Report" renderType="draw" theme="default">
```

After that, you can move the charts at the title or other bands

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if this is possible.But if you convert to pdf you can simply rearrange the pages with [iTetxt](http://itextpdf.com/) as a workaround.Or you can put the pie chart in the page header section of the report

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding Report Group header , there you can have a summary pie chart attached with sub dataset.